# Evaluate an integral of the Airy function $\operatorname{Bi}(x)$

Tags: special-functions, definite-integrals

How do I evaluate this interesting integral with the Airy function:

$$\int_0^x \operatorname{Bi}(u)^2 du$$

More generally, how do I evaluate

$$\int_0^x \operatorname{Bi}(u)^n du$$

Comment: You mean $\mathrm{Bi}(x) = \frac{1}{\pi} \int\limits_0^\infty \left(\exp\left(-\frac{t^3}{3} + xt\right) + \sin\left(\frac{t^3}{3} + xt\right)\right)\, {\rm d}t \;$? So what you tried so far? And why do you think it's interesting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first one is easy. We know that $\operatorname{Bi}^{\prime\prime}(z)=z\operatorname{Bi}(z)$ from the Airy differential equation, so

$$\begin{align*}
\int\operatorname{Bi}(z)^2\mathrm dz&=z\operatorname{Bi}(z)^2-2\int z\operatorname{Bi}(z)\operatorname{Bi}^\prime(z)\mathrm dz\\
&=z\operatorname{Bi}(z)^2-2\int\operatorname{Bi}^\prime(z)\operatorname{Bi}^{\prime\prime}(z)\mathrm dz\\
&=z\operatorname{Bi}(z)^2-\operatorname{Bi}^\prime(z)^2
\end{align*}$$

and then use the [initial conditions for the Airy differential equation](http://dlmf.nist.gov/9.2.ii) to yield

$$\int_0^z\operatorname{Bi}(t)^2\mathrm dt=z\operatorname{Bi}(z)^2-\operatorname{Bi}^\prime(z)^2+\frac{\sqrt[3]{3}}{\Gamma\left(\frac13\right)^2}$$

For $n=1$ in your more general integral, the [Scorer functions](http://dlmf.nist.gov/9.12) and their derivatives [are involved](http://dlmf.nist.gov/9.10.E3):

$$\int_0^z\operatorname{Bi}(t)\mathrm dt=\pi(\operatorname{Bi}(z)\operatorname{Hi}^\prime(t)-\operatorname{Bi}^\prime(z)\operatorname{Hi}(z))$$

Comment: what do you think about higher order, is it possible?

Comment: I haven't tried, it seems complicated...